# How to influence behavior of cancel button in UCropActivity

Tags: android, cropper, ucrop

I'm using the Yalantis library "UCrop" in my android app to crop, scale and rotate images coming from the built-in smartphone camera.
When I call `uCrop.start(this)` the `UCropActivity` launches and in the upper left corner the cancel button appears as a little cross.

Now when I press the cancel button, the app crashes with the following Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.myappname, PID: 25034 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myappname/com.myapp.myappname.myActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

When I press the softkey-back-button I return savely to `myActivity`.

Now the question is, how can I influence the behavior of the *cancel* button so that it either behaves like the *back* button or restarts `myActivity` in a way that doesn't cause an exception?

In the `SampleActivity` from the ucrop sample-project the *cancel* button behaves as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this issue I see with my app:

adding a `return true;` after the line `onBackPressed();` in the `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` method inside `UCropActivity` class will do the trick for me.

Don't ask me why it would behave different when I press the softkey back button.